# Expanding a div to contain content that overflows off the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a set up similar to the below wireframe. A container div, with a content div inside. The content div contains a number of buttons, the number of buttons is not fixed and is not known ahead of design time.

This is the actual result that I get. 
[image: actual result]

This is causing issues when trying to scroll the contents of `Container-div` as the scroll ends at the end of `content-div` not the end of the overflowing buttons. The buttons overflow outside of the div and off the screen.

This is my desired result:
[image: desired result]

I need the `content-div` to expand to contain all its content buttons within the scrollable area of `container-div`. All results I have found from searching for solutions do not appear to work. I am using Bootstrap 4 and I think that may have an effect on the outcome. Therefore, the solution needs to work with Bootstrap 4 (as it is used for the rest of the site). The solution also (unfortunately) needs to  be compatible with IE11+

**Edit** Relevant code (using Vue2 and JSX):

```
<div v-dragscroll on-scroll={this.contentScrolled} ref="prompt-container" id="prompt-container" class="mx-2"> 
    <div ref="prompt-container-contents" id="prompt-container-contents">
    {
        this.promptsToShow.map(prompt => ([
            <BBtn
                variant="outline-primary"
                class="h-100 prompt-wrap mr-1 prompt-item"
                size="sm"
                pill
                on-click={() => { this.$emit(this.emitting, prompt); }}>
                {prompt}
            </BBtn>,
            <BBtn
                variant="outline-primary"
                class="h-100 prompt-wrap mr-1 prompt-item"
                size="sm"
                pill
                on-click={() => { this.$emit(this.emitting, prompt); }}>
                {prompt}
            </BBtn>]
        ))
    }
    <BBtn
        v-show={this.highestIndexToShow < this.prompts.length - 1}
        class="h-100 prompt-wrap mr-1 prompt-item"
        key="next"
        size="sm"
        pill
        on-click={() => { this.page++; }}>
        Show More
    </BBtn>
</div>
```

```css
.prompt-wrap{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}

#prompt-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for people using IE */
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
}

#prompt-container-contents { 
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.prompt-item {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**Edit 2**
Code fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0r4hget3/1/

This is as close to a minimal reproduction as I can get. Interestingly the suggested fix I came across only works for this. Adding `float: left` to the `content-div` fixes the code in this fiddle.

As far as I can tell this float isn't being overridden anywhere when running my full code. Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this float to no-longer fix the problem?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: `.content-div {display: inline-block;}`  should do the trick.

Comment: @Teemu That didn't seem to have any effect. I've added my code to the question. I'll get started on trying to replicate a minimum example fiddle.

Comment: @DaFois See edit 2

Comment: @Jack [No?](https://jsfiddle.net/2vwjfka9/) The only difference is, that you've used the ID selector, which I wasn't aware based on the images only.

Comment: @Teemu Read the content of Edit 2 too.. I can fix it in the fiddle with `float: left` but that same fix does not work on the full code. What else could be affecting this?

Comment: @Teemu Please read the comment above the float property. I commented it out to show what I am getting even with `float:left` in my full code. For some reason, the fix that works in the fiddle, does not work in my code.

Comment: Then you should provide a full example of what you have. `display: inline-block` is an established solution to make a wrapper to adapt the width of its content. Notice, that your original fiddle code does not do what you want with  the float. If you'd add a border to `#div-content` you'd see the div is cut at the length of its parent, and what you see is the visible overflow of `#div-content`.

Comment: @Teemu See Edit 1. I cannot provide much more of a full example than that without dumping the entire codebase into a repo which I cannot do.

Comment: Then you should narrow it down so that the issue can be reproduced. It's frustrating to try to find an issue from a code where it isn't. Open DevTools in your favorite browser, and check which rules are affecting to the said div. That way you can create a fiddle, or rather a StackSnippet, and include all the affecting CSS-rules.

Comment: @Teemu [This](https://jsfiddle.net/0gtqy318/3/) is now exactly the same structure with exactly the same CSS classes as my compiled code and it still does not show the same issue I am having. I'm completely stumped as to what could be causing this.

Comment: Did you include the inherited rules too? Unfortunately it's not possible to answer the question, if there's not code to reproduce the issue. Btw. Does the -webkit -stuff for element scrolling in `#prompt-container` rule work for you?

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, all the rules shown in the computed rules line up, only difference is the font family. The -webkit stuff doesn't seem to work on fiddle but works on my code.

Comment: It works also in iOS?

Comment: I haven't tested in IOS yet